# No subgroup of $A_4$ of order $6$, hence $Z(A_4)$ is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. They are all specifically about Lagrange's Theorem and permutation groups. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

> Show that the fact that $A_4$ doesn't have subgroup of order 6 implies that $|Z(A_4)| = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these two facts :

1. If $H < Z(A_4)$, then $H\triangleleft A_4$
2. If $H\triangleleft G, K < G$, then $HK < G$. Furthermore, if $(|H|,|K|) = 1$, then $|HK| = |H||K|$

a) By Lagrange's theorem, $|Z(A_4)| \in \{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$.

b) Since $A_4$ is non-abelian and does not have a subgroup of order 6, $|Z(A_4)| \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

c) If $|Z(A_4)| = 2$, by Cauchy's thoerem, there is a subgroup $K < A_4$ such that $|K| = 3$. Hence, by (1) and (2), $A_4$ would have a subgroup of order 6 - A contradiction.

d) Similarly, $|Z(A_4)|\neq 3$.

e) If $|Z(A_4)| = 4$, then there exists $\sigma \in Z(A_4)$ of order 2, and $H = \langle \sigma \rangle$  is normal in $A_4$. As before, this would imply that $A_4$ has a subgroup of order 6.

Hence, $|Z(A_4)| = 1$

Comment: BTW, the easiest way to show that $A_4$ does not have a subgroup of order 6 is to compute its class equation, where you end up showing that $|Z(A_4)| = 1$ :)

Comment: How did you prove this ? then there exists σ∈Z(A4) of order 2, and H=⟨σ⟩ is normal in A4. Thanks.

Comment: Again, that is Cauchy's theorem

Answer (score 0):

Prove by contradiction. assume there is a nontrivial element $\sigma$ in center. then $o(\sigma)$ can be 2,3 or 4. now use the fact that $o(\sigma \eta) = [o(\sigma),o(\eta)] $. choose $\eta$ suitably to get an element of order 6.